# click on td is not working for all in dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i'm using dataTable plugin.

- i want to edit or delete the particular row, so onclick on `<td>` iam planning to    capture id.

but the problem  when i go to next tab onclick is not working. it is working only for the present item.

here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/UvjnT/1191/

Please click on the item and see the alert. Then go to next tab, click but will not work? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. You can see difference between .click() and .on("click") [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable({"sPaginationType": "full_numbers"});
   $('#example').on("click","td",function(){
     alert($(this).text());
   });
});
```

Comment: thank you very much it is working.